# currentInputMode alternative for IOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

as `currentInputMode` is Deprecated in iOS 7.0 
so what to use to get current input language

i tired with `activeInputModes` but that does not change the order

```
NSArray *currentar = [UITextInputMode activeInputModes];
UITextInputMode *current = [currentar firstObject];

NSString *primaryLanguage = current.primaryLanguage;
NSLog(@"Current text input is: %@", primaryLanguage);
```

Comment: i am still looking for a solution

Comment: So there is no alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: yourTextView.textInputMode.primaryLanguage;